# Is crockford's JavaScript constructor pattern really supposed to be faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, constructor

I recently tried to optimize some code for an often created value object. (A three dimensional vector, fwiw)

One thing I tried was to convert the constructor function from an anonymous method factory pattern to a normal JavaScript constructor.

This led to a [severe performance penalty](http://jsperf.com/ffs-constructors/5) which surprised me, since the use of 'new' and normal constructors was much recommended in my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744094/making-a-javascript-knockout-viewmodel-without-the-new-keyword) on the subject of JavaScript constructor/factory patterns.

It could well be that my test is too simplistic, or just plain wrong, or a result of recent performance optimizations made in chrome's JavaScript engine, or all of the above. In any case, I'd really like to know why my 'optimizations' led to performance drop - and - most important: Is there any obvious problem with my jsperf testrun?

Comment: crockford is fastest for me by ~50%

Comment: @Zaz: 2 things...1) Does crockford claim his method is faster? I thought it was just that it avoided globals and was therefore "safer".  2) Are you sure what you are showing there is what Crockford recommends?  I was thinking more along the lines of the last example on this page...http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html...if I'm wrong (probably) could you link me to where you're getting this from as I'm currently doing a reread of "The Good Parts"

Comment: you're comparing 2 things that don't do the same thing, neither of which is Crockford's object constructor.

Comment: @Mathletics: There would be no reason to compare two identical bits of code.  What behavioral or performance differences are there between the two techniques presented, beyond the construction performance difference already noted?

Comment: @ScottSauyet the question suggests he's testing Crockford's constructor; comparing setting `prototype` directly vs using the `new` keyword. Two methods of creating an object, but certainly not "identical bits of code." The entire question is about construction performance, but the tests provided aren't representative of the question that I think the OP thinks he's asking.

Comment: @Mathletics: Yes, this is definitely not either Crockford's older inheritance model or his newer `Object.create()` one, but both techniques presented are means of constructing instances of an "often created value object", which is how the question was formulated.  Granted that you can do different things with constructors than with factory functions, do you see any practical differences between the approaches presented here?

Comment: Mathletics is correct, I was confused regarding exactly what 'crockford constructor pattern' actually means. 

kekekela: What I mean is the pattern that appears in JavaScript The good parts, chapter 4 Functions, section Closure. 

ScottSauyet: Is the difference that with the 'new' keyword js has to keep track of prototype etc, but the anonymous object can stay lightweight?

Comment: @Zaz: Yes, but that's good and bad.  Sometimes it really helps to have the prototypes, for memory and for speed: http://jsperf.com/ffs-constructors/7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the things that a constructor function optimizes for is shared properties, usually methods.  If a number of objects use the same functions as methods, or share other named properties, then one assignment to the prototype will share a single instance of the property among all objects created from the constructor, reducing memory overhead, and will not need to repeat the assignment of each such property for every object created, reducing construction time overhead.

Since your sample does not include any such properties, you're not going to see such benefits.  But if your production code does not include shared properties for your constructed object, there might well be no reason to switch to a constructor.

So, if, for example you had code [like this](http://jsperf.com/ffs-constructors/7):

```
function make(p) {
    return {
        parm: p,
        addTwo: function() {return this.parm + 2;},
        double: function() {return this.parm * 2;},
        square: function() {return this.parm * this.parm;}
    };
};
```

it will probably run more slowly than this:

```
function Make(p) {
    this.parm = p;
}
Make.prototype.addTwo = function() {return this.parm + 2;};
Make.prototype.double = function() {return this.parm * 2;}
Make.prototype.square = function() {return this.parm * this.parm;}
```

It will also take a lot more memory if you create many instances.

Comment: So my problem was that while my original pattern was bad, my 'optimization' wasn't better. I refactored the vector class to use prototype for its functions like you suggested and my code got eight times faster. Thanks for the help. : )

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Not quite sure why people down-voted the answer.  This is not the only pattern to use for creating such objects.  You might investigate `Object.create()`, which is available in most modern JS engines and can be shimmed for these uses in others.  It's probably widely considered the more modern solution, but will have similar performance characteristics to this one.

Answer (score 4):

The major differences between your tests are:

- [`{}` is way faster than `new Object`](http://jsperf.com/new-object-versus), which suggests that `new` is simply slower than using `{}`. (The same is true of `[]` and `new Array`.)
- Your tests produce different results: the result of your `make` factory function isn't a `Make` object. The constructed `Make` has a prototype, shared by all `Make` objects. Your result of your factory function is just a bare `Object`, and has a single prototype in its prototype chain (`Object.prototype`), whereas the Make constructed object has two (`Make.prototype`, followed by `Object.prototype`).

  I made a [fork of your test](http://jsperf.com/ffs-constructors/8), with a factory function that actually returns a `Make` object (instead a simple `Object`), using the non-standard `__proto__` property, and it is much slower than a using a constructor. IE does not support `__proto__`, but the results from Firefox and Chrome look pretty definitive.

Comment: I like both Scott's answer and your answer. I think yours is clearer, especially the point about `Object` vs `Make`. Thanks!